# How do I solve this scanner issue? I want the four actions to work but whenever I type it in and click enter it doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a bootleg pokemon game but this scanner isn't working.

`JavaBattle` object is instantiated inside of driver. Everything works in the driver, but this code doesn't. "Cyclone", "Tornado Spin", "Thermal" and "Huff 'n Puff" all should work but don't on the first try.

I don't really know what I should do.

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaBattle{
    private int opponentHealth;

    public void fight(){
        opponentHealth = 100;
        Scanner attackchoice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Attacks:\nCylcone\nTornado Spin\nThermal\nHuff 'n Puff");
        System.out.println("Choose One:");
        String ability = attackchoice.nextLine();
        if(!ability.equals("Cyclone")||!ability.equals("Tornado 
Spin")||!ability.equals("Thermal")||!ability.equals("Huff 'n Puff")){
            System.out.println("Not available. Please Try Again.");
            System.out.println("Attacks:\nCylcone\nTornado Spin\nThermal\nHuff 'n Puff");
            System.out.println("Choose One: ");
            ability = attackchoice.nextLine();
        }
        int randAttackDamage = (int)(Math.random()*16)+15;
        int randOpponentAttack = (int)(Math.random()*21)+10;
        System.out.println(ability + " was used." + "("+randAttackDamage+")");
        opponentHealth = opponentHealth - randAttackDamage;
        System.out.println("Opponents Current Health: " + opponentHealth);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!value==1 || !value==2)` will always enter the `then` block because the value can't be equal to all those values at once. You want `if (!value==1 && !value==2)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your logical OR operators `||` with AND operators `&&`. With the code you have, your `if` clause is only true if `ability` is all four of the abilities at once. You want to check if the ability is none of the available abilities.